# block all VM connections but forward to a single host

Tags: virtualbox, routing, firewall

I want to restrict internet access of a virtual windows machine. I want this machine to be able to reach a certain IP address and upload/dowload files from this server. I set up an OPNsense installation with two NIC: one is connected to the isolated virtual network with the windows PC, the other is a bridged adapter being part of my LAN. How do I only forward packets from or to this certain IP and drop all other traffic? I have 10.0.0.0/8 for the isolated virtual network and 192.168.178.0/24 for my LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very easy. Set up an internal network in Virtualbox adapter settings. Connected both the firewall and the windows PC to this network as first network adapter. Connected a second, bridged adapter to the firewall.

Started the installation of opnsense, assign the bridged adapter as WAN, the internal network connected adapter as LAN. Assigned IPs on command line, then using the webui installer and after finishing deleted the default ipv4/6 allow-everything rules from Firewall-LAN section, add a new rule to allow inbound traffic with source lan-net, destination was the IP in question. Works perfectly!